# Access to TextBoxes in all ListView rows - WPF - VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How can I access to TextBoxes in all ListView rows? I have also tried the two-way method, but it is only one-way.

```
<ListView Name="ListViewParameters" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="120" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="TextWidth" Text="{Binding Path=Width, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
...
```

.

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Initialized(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Initialized
       ListViewParameters.ItemsSource = Parameters
End Sub
```

.

```
Public Structure Parameter
    Private _width As Integer
    Private _length As Integer
    Private _height As Integer
    Property Width() As Integer
        Get
            Return _width
        End Get
        Set(Value As Integer)
            _width = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Length() As Integer
        Get
            Return _length
        End Get
        Set(Value As Integer)
            _length = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property Height() As Integer
        Get
            Return _height
        End Get
        Set(Value As Integer)
            _height = Value
        End Set
    End Property
End Structure

Public ReadOnly Parameters As New ObservableCollection(Of Parameter)
```

My goal is to calculate the volume:

Private Sub ButtonCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
Dim volume As Integer = 1
For Each t As TextBox In ListParameters
volume *= CInt(t.Text)
Next
MsgBox(volume.ToString)
End Sub

(This is for learning only)

Comment: Not an answer but in this situation you’re far better off putting the calculated field in your backing structure then you just need to display it with standard bindings

Comment: @Hursey I don't know how. Can you explain more, please?